# TFS2015 witadmin exportwitd Error

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I am using on-premise TFS 2015(15.117.27024.0).  I created a new root project and wanted to export the Work Item definitions so I can add a few fields that are not in the default layout, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-manage-wits?view=tfs-2015)

I can export the project config and categories without any issue.

The command I am running(replaced URL with example.com):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\witadmin" exportwitd /collection:"https://tfs.example.com/tfs" /p:"Library" /n:"Feature" /f:"Library_Feature.xml"
```

Result:

```
API resource location 8637ac8b-5eb6-4f90-b3f7-4f2ff576a459 is not registered on https://tfs.example.com/tfs.
```

I did this several years ago for another project but never had this problem.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you checked this issue on other clients? Does it work? I mean run the export command on another Visual Studio client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested on my side, cannot reproduce your issue, everything works as expected.

Whatever you can try below items to narrow down the issue:

- Please check if you have specified the correct URL, make sure no any
  spelling errors.
- Try running the export command on another machine which installed VS.
- Try to export the WIT definition file with **Process Editor** (Power
  Tools)

  Visual Studio 2015 : [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server
  2015 Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power)

  Visual Studio 2017 : [TFS Process Template Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KarthikBalasubramanianMSFT.TFSProcessTemplateEditor)

Comment: Even though the "exportcategories" and "exportprocessconfig" commands worked with one URL apparently the "exportwitd" doesn't.  I installed the Power Tools, and when looking at editing templates I noticed the URL the power tool provided was different. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Also, that Power Tool is very useful.  The GUI for updating the WIT is nice.

Answer (score -2):

You're missing **collection name** in API request:

Error:

```
/collection:http://MyServer:8080/
```

Success:

```
/collection:http://MyServer:8080/tfs/TeamProjectCollectionName
```